# What middle tier and backend libraries exist for handling player matching and out of game information?

Tags: ranking, tournament

Are there any libraries or frameworks readily available that handle player metrics, rankings, matching, tournaments, etc? Anything for managing the player community? (Please don't say [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/))

Comment: Ok, I am now officially hooked again.  In an effort to give something back, I want to find places I can leverage my current skill-set to help the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of frameworks depending on the target platform.

- On PC, you can use [Steamworks](http://www.steampowered.com/steamworks/)
- Xbox 360 and PS3 both have matchmaking for full-on developers
- For independent games, XNA allows acess to a limited set of Xbox Live features

I can't think of any others, so beyond these you'd likely have to build your own.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any, so I'm building something in this vein more or less from scratch.  Currently just using libcurl on the client side and Django on the server side as bases.

Comment: Cool toolset.  So you are using libcurl to post back a results file and a custom Django application to interpret and present?

Comment: Right now it's just a GET request on the client, but yes, the Django app handles most of the logic (when necessary).  I suspect there will be more presentation code on the client side than I'd like (since server-side code is easier to change post-ship), but integrating a web browser would be overkill ;)

Answer (score 1):

[ElectroServer4](http://www.electro-server.com/) was pointed out in another question as being an off the shelf middle tier.