# Match Making Groups of Players

Tags: ranking, tournament, matchmaking

Given a situation where I have a pool of `X` people of different scores (ranks) `S` with game size `N`. How do I partition the pool into `N` sized games where the standard deviation of ranks for each games is minimized?

(quality of the game is inversely proportional to STD of ranks)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/464/what-middle-tier-and-backend-libraries-exist-for-handling-player-matching-and-out though a smaller subset.

Comment: @The Communist Duck I don't really want a framework. I'm looking to code it myself, so I need an algorithm (or heuristics).

Comment: It's not clear what you want to happen when N|X fails. Does N vary over some range? Can I make games with anywhere between 2 and N players? Are you looking to minimize the mean, total, or some other function of the standard deviations?

Comment: @Joe Wreschnig You can assume N % X == 0. Any N is an acceptable number, but N = 1 is the trivial case.

Answer (score 1):

If your values for X and N are very large, it would probably make the most sence to keep the player list sorted by `Rank` such that you could always take the bottom `N` elements to create a group. This will front-load your computation time (keeping the list sorted every time you add a new item), in contrast with the above algorithm which would require execution every time a new group is to be created.

Comment: I've looked over this algorithm a bit and I can't understand the logic or it's result *at all*. Could you explain it a bit more? Why would I want a `groupMembers filled with the index of players with the smallest rank`? I've reworded the question, maybe that'll help make what I'm asking for more clear.

Comment: -1 - I think you're trying to do the same thing I suggested, but your actual code is nonsense. If players[0] has the smallest rank, your code provides garbage in groupMembers. If players[0] has the second-smallest, your code produces a group of N copies of the smallest group member. And so on.

Comment: After rereading the question and your updated explination, my code (even fixed) wouldn't have done what you want; that said, it is wrong, I'd copied it and removed some important bits.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not mathematically optimal (optimality in this case reeks of NP to me, but I'm not certain), but assuming N is fixed and a unimodal, approximately normal S distribution  you should be able to get something close to optimal just sorting by rank and slicing a group off every N players.